# Magnetic susceptibility in the spin triplet channel

Tags: feynman-diagrams, many-body, correlation-functions

In the literature and articles I sometimes see the phrase magnetic/electric  susceptibility(or other kinds of correlation functions) in the triplet channel. I don't know what does it exactly mean. From quantum mechanics I think that an spin triplet state should be something like :
$$
c^{\dagger}_{p\uparrow}c^{\dagger}_{k\uparrow}|gs\rangle \, \, or \, \, c^{\dagger}_{p\downarrow}c^{\dagger}_{k\downarrow}|gs\rangle \, \, or \, \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(c^{\dagger}_{p\uparrow}c^{\dagger}_{k\downarrow}|gs\rangle +c^{\dagger}_{p\downarrow}c^{\dagger}_{k\uparrow}|gs\rangle)
$$

For calculating the response functions we need to calculate correlation functions like :

$$
\sum_{p,p,\sigma,\sigma'}\langle T c^{\dagger}_{k,\sigma}c_{k+q,\sigma}c^{\dagger}_{p+q,\sigma'}c_{p,\sigma'}\rangle\, \, \, \, (for\,\, electric\, \, susceptibility)
$$
$$
\sum_{p,p,\sigma,\sigma'}\sigma \sigma'\langle T c^{\dagger}_{k,\sigma}c_{k+q,\sigma}c^{\dagger}_{p+q,\sigma'}c_{p,\sigma'}\rangle\, \, \, \, (for\,\, magnetic\, \, susceptibility)
$$

If there is interactions then we can use Feynman diagrams (in along with other approximation methods like RPA) to calculate these correlation functions.So everything about performing calculations is known. But I just can't relate the concept of a triplet spin state to these correlation functions. How we can separate the triplet and singlet contributions in Feynman diagrams.


Here is an article in which the authors talk about this concept :
[Predicting a Gapless Spin-1 Neutral Collective Mode branch for Graphite](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0110022v1)